# Use username for Exchange email account with Windows 10 mail app

Tags: email, exchange, windows-8-mail-app

Up untill yesterday, my email was working fine - I have my home and college accounts on the Mail app - that's a Live.com, an IMAP GMail and an Exchange with my college.

Yesterday, the college changed the system to use a username for signin rather than an email.

My username is `AB123456` and my email is `AB123456@college.ac.uk`.

This is fine online, on OWA (`mail.college.ac.uk/owa`), but Mail doesn't accept a non email address as a username. Can I make mail accept my username? Or alternatively set up outlook in the same way?

Comment: Have you tried AB123456@college.ac.uk as the Username?

Comment: @RMarkwald Yes, that's what it is currently set up with (it no longer works). My college just changed it to be just `AB123456`.